# How to remove unused javascript for page load score

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, lighthouse

My website is [winions.gg](https://winions.gg) (built with React), and Google Lighthouse is telling me that I need to remove unused javascript to load the page faster. I'm not sure where to even start, because in my mind all the javascript is being used. Do I have to defer something? How can I accomplish this

[image: unused js]

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import './style.css'

//Routing
import { BrowserRouter as Router , Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom"

import Header from "./Components/Layout/Header";
import Footer from "./Components/Layout/Footer";
import HomePage from "./Components/Home/HomePage";
import ProfilePage from "./Components/Profile/ProfilePage";
import AllArticles from "./Components/AllArticles/AllArticles";
import Pricing from "./Components/Pricing/Pricing";

const App = () => (
    <Router>
      <Header/>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path = '/' element={<Pricing/>}/>
        {/* <Route exact path = '/profile' element={<ProfilePage/>}/>
        <Route exact path = '/player/:playerRegion/:playerName' element={<ProfilePage/>}/>
        <Route exact path = '/allarticles' element={<AllArticles/>}/>
        <Route exact path = '/old-homepage' element ={<HomePage/>}/> */}
      </Routes>
      <Footer/>
    </Router>
  );

export default App
```

Index.js

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Edit: I think I'm using webpack. The bundle.js file is definitely the biggest file

Comment: What are you using to build the JavaScript? WebPack, Rollup, etc...?

Comment: I didn't primarily build the website, which is where my lack of knowledge comes from. I do see lots of mentions of webpack in the packagelock, but I don't see any mention of it anywhere else

Comment: Take a look at: [_Slim down your webpack bundle: Effectively reducing loading time_](https://benedikt-roetsch.de/blog/reduce-website-loading-time-via-webpack-bundle-optimization)

Comment: The problem is that I don't see a webpack config, or CLI, or anything else. The only mention of webpack in my entire project is in the pack json files, and my build folder

Comment: Include your "scripts" JSON definition, within your `package.json`, in your question.

Comment: In my (admittedly limited) experience, I find that often, the `webpack.config.js` file is not generated by default when you create a new project/package (I use `create-react-app`).  I have to manually create the file at the top-level directory (as a sibling to `package.json` et al).  I'm sure others will let me know if I am doing something wacky, but that has been my experience and I wonder if it might be yours as well.